# Fourier transform does not produce the correct result

Tags: signal-processing, matlab, fourier

I am trying to calculate the absolute value of a certain sinusoid to see how MATLAB calculates the Fourier Transform by using the freqz() command. Here is my Matlab code

```
    Np=20;
    n=0:1:Np-1;
    s1=[sin(2*pi/Np*n)];
    h1=freqz(s1);
    figure(1);
    plot(abs(h1));
```

And the plotted result is: 
[image]

My question is:
My theoretical plot should only show one "bar". Why doesn't it do that? Is my code wrong?

Comment: You only have a small interval, so the sine wave is truncated. Theory assumes it goes to infinity.

Comment: How many sine wave cycles did your math consider?

Comment: The transformed window does not contain an exact multiple of the desired singular frequency

Comment: Mário, sure you want `freqz` and not just `abs(fft)`?

Comment: Marcus, its a lab problem, firstly, we use freqz and then we use fft to see the differences between the two commands.

Comment: Have you *read the documentation for freqz*?

Answer (score 1):

As @MarcusMüller indicated, you need to use `fft` instead of `freqz`:

Replace `h1=freqz(s1);` with `h1=fft(s1)/Np;`
Also, to interpret the result, it would be better to replace `plot(abs(h1));` with `stem(n,abs(h1));`.

In your example, the signal is exactly one period of a sine wave with amplitude 1, so you should get a spike at n=1 and n=19 with amplitude one half. The amplitude of 1 is split over two frequencies. The n=19 corresponds to a negative frequency n=-1 (a sine wave is the sum of two complex exponentials, one with a positive frequency and one with a negative frequency: \$\sin(\omega t) = \frac{1}{2 j}(e^{j \omega t} - e^{-j \omega t})\$).

If you would want to plot a single-sided FFT (this has only positive frequencies and would provide an amplitude of one at n=1 in your example), have a look at [the Matlab documentation for fft, example Noisy Signal](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-9).